# Creating Fade In / Fade Out effects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have grid class in javascript and when hover on some areas, an different image displays. I want this image to fade in/ fade out when displayed.
Hereby an exemple of the effect (could't figure out how it was made) : https://dustinthierry.com/

I am not sure how I should do it, as I am not directly using the CSS :hover .
Any leads ?

```js
         for (let i = 0; i < hovergrid.length; i++) {

        if (hovergrid[i].hover(mouseX, mouseY)) {
            console.log("hover on " + i)

            hovergrid[i].display(i)
        }


    }

    display(number) {

       this.img = document.getElementById("displayedimage")
        this.img.style.display = "block"
        this.img.src = "images/" + number + ".jpg"
       
        this.img.style.right = this.posx + "px"
        this.img.style.bottom = this.posy + "px"
        this.img.alt = picdes[number]
```

```css
#displayedimage {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 30%;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide minimal code to reproduce this using snippet editor?

Comment: it (dustinthierry) just uses the `:hover` psuedo selector and `transition: opacity .2s` — which I easily found with my brower's _inspect element_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use plain CSS for that effect. Using plain CSS will simplify your code, and also let you use CSS transitions.
Here's a rundown of what you could do:

- Put your normal elements inside a Div (as in the OPULENCE text in the example)
- Make your Div's position `Relative`. This will allow you to position certain elements inside of it, inside the dive
- Create an overlay element that that is normally transparent
- Put your images inside the overlay and make them invisible: `opacity:0`
- Upon the hover of your overlay element, you can change the opacity of the image inside of it: `div.overlay:hover > img {opacity: 1}`.

```css
.container{
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  background:black;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}
h1{
  text-align:center;
  color:#ffffff;
  margin-top:30px;
}
.overlay{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:transparent;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
.overlay img{
  width:200px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:50px;
  right:20px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  opacity:0;
}

.overlay:hover > img{
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Some text here</h1>
  <div class="overlay">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532842-98d0fd5ebc1a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note that because of the positionings, your overlay doesn't necessarily have to contain the whole element. It can be in a place, totally irrelevant to the image.
Also if you want to have more than one image, you can split your overlay into more inner elements that each have an image, and do the same thing for all of them.
This cleans up your Javascript and gives you all the CSS functionalities needed.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately, the grid of images is different from the hovergrid I built from javascript, so I need to keep it this way.